# How to highlight dates between fromDate and toDate, Jquery datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have created a JS fiddle with my current code. What I want is to highlight the days between the selected "from" date all the way until the "to" date. For example if I select 29.01.2014 as my from date and the 02.02.2014 as my to date, all dates in between should be highlighted.

Also, if anyone could guide me on making the minDate for the "to" date be either the current date or the date selected in the From picker, that would be great.

What I have so far. Fiddle below.

```
$(function () {
    $("#From").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        gotoCurrent: true,
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: "+1y",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#To").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});

$(function () {
    $("#To").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        gotoCurrent: true,
        minDate: "From",
        maxDate: "+1y",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#From").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4n4Cu/

Comment: Im not sure I understand. Where do you want to highlight the date if already both dates have been selected? You mean if the user selects both dates and then decides to change to-date, it would hightlight the current timespan in the calendar?

Comment: Something like this where the from date and to date are in a darker color and the dates in between are in a lighter shade. [date-range](http://imgur.com/WPoJX09)

Comment: Do you only want to set minDate of To Datepicker to From Date ?

Comment: The user should not be able to select a date in the To picker that is further back in time than the current day, however if the user selects a date in the From datepicker, that should be the new minDate for the To picker.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to this

```
$(function () {
    $("#To").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        gotoCurrent: true,
        minDate:$("#From").val() == ""|| undefined ? 0 : $("#From").val() ,
        maxDate: "+1y",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#From").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```